# Visual studio creates unusual files automatically when Press CTRL + S

Tags: c#, visual-studio

First Let me explain the scenario.

I have create on resx(resource file) for storing messages for exception and success messages.

I have added 10 values in resource file. Suddenly When I add 11 value in resource file and press CTRL + S. The new designer file create automatically. I can't understand this issue.

[image: Please look at images for more understanding]

Comment: **SuccessMessages1.Designer.cs** is auto generated file.

Comment: If I Use Access Modifire - No Code Generation. Then this issue getting resolved. What is the use of No Code Generation in resource file..?